# HoloEveryWhere not changing ActionBarColor on ICS + - Custom theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

I am using HoloEveryWhere Library with `Holo.Theme.Sherlock.Light` as the parent theme. I am also using `splitActionBarWhenNarrow` and so the top `ActionBar` and bottom `ActionBar` will be of Light colors. I would like to have dark color in top `ActionBar`, so I have changed it programmatically and it works fine.

As I have Light theme as parent and dark color in top `ActionBar`, the `homeAsUpIndcator` will be of dark color which is not visible in a dark top `ActionBar`.

Thus I have created a custom theme to make the `homeAsUpIndcator` a light one. I have succeeded in what I need using this theme :

`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Holo.Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/abs__ic_ab_back_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/abs__ic_ab_back_holo_dark</item>
</style>
```

`

This is working perfectly in Android 2.2 Emulator but not in ICS+ I am getting the dark  bottom `ActionBar` and `ActionPopupMenus` :(

Actually I did not specify any Dark theme anywhere!
Am I missing any attributes for the custom theme ?

Comment: Do you have a values-v11 folder?

Comment: @Ahmad, quick and precise! It worked ! :) thank you so much

Comment: @Ahmad, please post as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you have a values-v11 folder where you also have your theme declared('AppTheme'). You can remove the style(if you don't plan to do something else with it)